# $(1+\sqrt 2)^{2006}=a+b\sqrt 2$ calculate $a^2-2b^2$

Tags: number-theory

Im having problem solving this one : $(1+\sqrt 2)^{2006}=a+b\sqrt 2$ calculate $a^2-2b^2$

I remarqued that if i show that $$(1-\sqrt 2)^{2006}=a-b\sqrt 2$$ then i get $$a^2-2b^2=1$$

I tried th newton's binomial but i got lost in calculation. I know about the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt 2]$ so maybe there is an easy thechnique?

Comment: Hint: $N(x+y\sqrt2)$ is multiplicative.

Comment: Prove that the map $x+y\sqrt{2}\mapsto x-y\sqrt{2}$ preserves multiplication and apply this to your equation.

Comment: i think you meant $N:a+b\sqrt 2 \mapsto a^-2b^2$, it worked

Comment: leoli1, is there any algebraic way to do this problem?

Answer (score 1):

$$a^2-2b^2=(a+b\sqrt{2})(a-b\sqrt{2})$$  so we multiply the two conjugates together,

$$(1+\sqrt{2})(1-\sqrt{2})=-1$$ and the answer is

$$(-1)^{2006}=1$$

Comment: I think he said that the issue is proving that $(1-\sqrt 2)^{2006}=a-b\sqrt 2$

Comment: @Andrei yes exactly